# Adding multi-line text to a single cell in a csv after _scraping_ a site

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

As the title suggests, I'm struggling to figure out how to make it so that a multiline block of text can fit in a single cell. As for some context to what I'm doing, I'm using Beautiful Soup to extract the mtDNA sequence along with other data on the site and put these values in a csv.

I've tried using `str.strip('\n')` to the text a single line, but that didn't work and the text ended up flowing to the next row as well. Below is my code for my program.

```
import requests

theSequenceLink = 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.fcgi?id=1877761016&db=nuccore&report=fasta&extrafeat=null&conwithfeat=on&hide-cdd=on&retmode=html&withmarkup=on&tool=portal&log$=seqview&maxdownloadsize=1000000'
res = requests.get(theSequenceLink)
dna_sequence = res.text.strip()

#cleaning up the sequence
split = 'genome'
mtDNA_sequence = dna_sequence.partition(split)[2]

#you can ignore the genbank and haplogroup stuff
f.write(genbank_ID + ", " + haplogroup.replace(",", "|") + ", " + mtDNA_sequence + "\n")
```

Any help towards solving this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Strip the `\n` after splitting `mtDNA_sequence = dna_sequence.partition(split)[2].strip()` and include the sequence in quotes so that csv can understand it's a single sequence

Comment: Do you happen to know how I should go about including the entire sequence in quotes when the sequence is expressed as a variable?

Comment: What all info you would want to store in csv?

Comment: I want to store the genbank sample ID, the haplogroup, and the entire sequence. I have no problem with the first two, it's just the sequence that messes everything up because the sequence will span across multiple rows and mess up the spreadsheet instead of it all being in one cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the dna sequence has newline characters in it. So, you will have to replace the newline characters.

```
import requests
theSequenceLink = 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.fcgi?id=1877761016&db=nuccore&report=fasta&ext
rafeat=null&conwithfeat=on&hide-cdd=on&retmode=html&withmarkup=on&tool=portal&log$=seqview&maxdownloadsize=10
00000'
res = requests.get(theSequenceLink)
dna_sequence = res.text.strip()

#cleaning up the sequence
split = 'genome'
mtDNA_sequence = dna_sequence.partition(split)[2].strip().replace("\n","")

f = open("a.csv","w")
genbank_ID = "hi"
haplogroup = "world"

#you can ignore the genbank and haplogroup stuff
f.write(genbank_ID + ", " + haplogroup.replace(",", "|") + ", \"" + mtDNA_sequence + "\"\n")
f.close()
```